# Possible differences between a vector space and the action of a multiplicative group of a field over an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

This comes from a discussion over a different question.

I proposed as an alternative definition of vector space this definition:

> Let $K$ a field, and $V$ an abelian group. Then a vector space can be defined as the action of the multiplicative group $K$ over $V$.

But someone tell me that this is wrong because not every actions of multiplicative groups have the structure of a vector space. In particular @TobiasKildetoft tell me that

> Take for example the trivial action of any cyclic group of order $p−1$ on any abelian group with more than one element and check that this does not correspond to a vector space over the field with $p$ elements.

I was thinking about the multiplicative group of some $\Bbb Z_p:=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ where $p$ is prime. Then let an abelian group $G$ with $p$ elements, if I understood correctly (cause the multiplicative group of $\Bbb Z_p$ have $p-1$ elements). But I dont see clearly how to prove the statement from here, i.e. that this structure is not a vector space.

I have defined vector spaces with three axioms (based but rephrased from *Analysis I* of Amann and Escher):

- (SV1) $(V,+)$ is an abelian group
- (SV2) the distributive law holds between the multiplicative operation of the field $K$ and the additive operation of the group $V$.
- (SV3) the multiplicative group of $K$ acts over $V$ and $0_K\cdot v=0_V$ for all $v\in V$.

Based on that the condition for the difference between a vector space an my unfortunate definition is (SV2) and the case $0v$ on (SV3), i.e. the distributive law between $K$ and $V$ doesnt not necessarily holds on my definition.

I tried an easy check based in the example of @TobiasKildetoft with the multiplicative group of $\Bbb Z_3$ and a simple group $G=\{0,a,b\}$ but this hold the conditions for a vector space:

- let $1\cdot a=a$ and so on, and $a+a=b$, $b+b=a$, $a+b=0$, $2b=a$ and $2a=b$. But then the distributive law holds for all cases, and the cases where $0v=0$, so Im lost.

**Questions:**

1. Is my assumption that the difference between my definition and a vector space is (SV2)? If not, what is the difference?
2. Some easy example that shows this difference?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For $K=\Bbb F_2$, the multiplicative group is trivial, hence an action is nothing special - but not every abelian group is an $\Bbb F_2$ vector space.